# How to analyze that IRC can't connect server?

Tags: irc

I want to connect `IRC` server, and after trying many ports: 6665, 6666, 8001, 8002, etc. I find I can't connect to server. From the `wireshark`, I can find there is no response from server:

[image]

Could anyone give some clues or tips about how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

normal ports are 6697 6667 7000 and some use 9001

Comment: 9001 still can't work. I suspect the root cause is not related to port but network.

Comment: what network (s)  I regularly park on 11 networks

Comment: `11 network`? What is the meaning?

Comment: as in I connect to 11 IRC networks which one or ones are you attempting to connect to